# Pass Json string to JQuery NOT using getJson()

Tags: jquery, json, jqplot

Very new to both `JSON` and `jQuery`, but here is what I am trying to do - I am returning a `JSON` string to my webpage as part of a bigger report model in order to create a number of graphs (using `jqPlot`) at the same time the report is generated.

To practice with these charts, I was using the following tutorial - [Tutorial](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2009/08/31/charts-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-through-jqplot/)

Here is the `jQuery` from this tutorial -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    urlDataJSON = '/Graph/HearthRateDataJSON';

    $.getJSON(urlDataJSON, "", function(data) {
        var dataLines = [];
        var dataLabels = "";
        $.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
            dataLines.push(entry['Serie']);
            dataLabels = dataLabels + entry['Name'];
        });

        Plot(dataLines, dataLabels);
    });
});

function Plot(dataLines, dataLabels) {
    var line1 = "{ label: 'line1.0' }";
    options = {
        legend: { show: true },
        title: 'Heart rate overview',
        axesDefaults: { pad: 1 },
        seriesDefaults: { showMarker: false, trendline: { show: false }, lineWidth: 3 },
        axes: {
            yaxis: { min: 0, autoscale: true, label: 'HR[bpm]', labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer },
            xaxis: { autoscale: true, label: 'Time', labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }
        }
    };

    //Data from database is already an array!
    plot = $.jqplot('chartdiv', dataLines, options);

    plot.redraw(); // gets rid of previous axis tick markers
}
```

To retrieve the `JSON` data, this tutorial uses the getJson() method to point to a link. I have the `JSON` string ready to pass through to the `jQuery` however, e.g.

```
[
    {"Name":"Patient","Serie":[[1,4],[2,25],[3,7],[4,14],[5,13]]},
    {"Name":"Test","Serie":[[1,13],[2,5],[3,7],[4,20],[5,17]]}
]
```

In the `jqPlot` examples, they pass hardcoded data through as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});
```

However, my automatically generated `JSON` string has the curly braces, etc. Is there a way to pass this through to `jQuery` without using the getJson method?

EDIT-Pie Chart Jquery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data4 = '[{ "Label": "Car", "Value": 9 },{ "Label": "Bus", "Value": 2 },{ "Label": "Train", "Value": 7 },{ "Label": "Plane", "Value": 8 },{ "Label": "Boat", "Value": 4 }]';

        var data = $.parseJSON(data4);

        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('pieChart', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
    });
```

Comment: You can parse (without the GET request) using $.parseJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: What exactly are you looking for, another $.ajax shortcut, using $.ajax, using XMLhttpRequest, or not using Ajax at all and just parsing a string or something else entirely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse it with any suggested methods provided in other answers and then using it. Or just simply use the `JSON` data you have as it is an array and all in `{}` treat as maps. Therefore, you can use them straight without any parsing [as I do in a similar situation shown in the code available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cVPjF/7/)

In the sample provided there is `JSON` data encoded in variable called json.

```
var json = [{
    "Name": "Poll Results",
    "Serie": [[2, 5, 4], [4, 1, 7], [6, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2]]}];
var dataLines = json[0].Serie;
var title = json[0].Name;
```

Then at the end `dataLines` variable is passed to the chart.

**EDIT**

After playing with the sample you provided I came to the following conclusions.
Apparently the given data is not a format of JSON that the parseJSON method of jQuery can work with. But when you [stringify](https://gist.github.com/754454) it works.

[My sample showing it works fine after application of stringify on the data.](http://jsfiddle.net/3cbVW/3/)

I tried and turned your JSON into a its String equivalent by wrapping it inside `''` and it worked. So the answer is simple to use `parseJSON` method you must pass it a String and not an Object of any other sort.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think I'd rather go ahead with parsing the Json, as I *almost* have this working. The chart generates but looks like there is no data for it. I tested the parse method here - http://jsfiddle.net/3cbVW/ ..as you can see it is returning null. Is there something I am doing wrong with it?

Comment: I have also included the Jquery for the pie chart I am trying to generate, if it's of any interest.

Comment: Please check out my **EDIT**. Therefore, think again if it is worth to parse the object again? :)

Comment: Oh god, ha. I think I'll leave the parsing alone...Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

use parseJSON:

```
 var plotline =  $.parseJSON(jsonstring);
```

this will work like getJSON, only instead of getting a url, you can pass on your string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @Rodik...this seems to be exactly what I need. I have tried it however and my graph is not displaying :S Is there any way to see the output of the parsed json string?

Comment: use a console enabled browser, and use console.log(plotline);

Answer (score 2):

You can  also use browser's native `JSON.parse` method