# How to parse jquery.sheet's JSON in Java?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc

I am using jquery.sheet plugin which accepts `JSON`. The `JSON` format is:

```
[
    { //repeats
        metadata: {
            columns: Column_Count,
            rows: Row_Count,
            title: ''
        },
        data: {
            r{Row_Index}: { //repeats
                c{Column_Index}: { //repeats
                    value: '',
                    style: '',
                    width: 0,
                    cl: {Classes used for styling}
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

A simple example may be:

```
[
    { 
        metadata: {
            columns: 1,
            rows: 1,
            title: 'Private Limited'
        },
        data: {
            r0: { 
                c0: { 
                    value: 'A',
                    style: '',
                    width: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I need to parse this `JSON` in `Java`? I know I can use the google's `gson` library to parse. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The bad thing is that rows and column names are not consistent, r0, r1, r2, c0, c1, c2,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Strictly speaking the sample you are referring to is not a valid `JSON`, e.g. it lacks "" around field ids as `metadata` [according to JSON defined in www.json.org][http://json.org/]*

For this reason **I would recommend** that before you pass it to your `Java` (e.g. servlet) you should stringify this object, e.g. [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10537607/613495). This way you are sure that this is a valid `JSON`. Later use `jQuery` to send it to servlet. There in your `Java` code you use the below code to get your `json` String turned into `JSONArray` on which you will operate further.

```
String json = request.getParameter(param);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Then you can iterate over its elements as if it was any other collection.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   //work with the jsonObject
}
```

[The `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` classes are taken from here.](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java)

[The jar for the library is availalbe here.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211)

You could use `gson` if you like. Though in this particular case this library is more then enough. I personally use `gson` if I have a bean object for a corresponding `JSON` String, otherwise `json.org` is more than enough.